# How to create a discord.js lock command

Tags: javascript, locking, discord, discord.js, unlock

I'm trying to create a lock and unlock command for my discord.js bot. How would I be able to do this?

I want to make it so when I do >lock it takes permission away from Verified to `SEND_MESSAGES`.

Then if I do >unlock, it unlocks the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, you just need to call the following lines to remove the permissions,

```
const role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

role.permissions.remove('SEND_MESSAGES')
```

and to give them back, just put the following lines under the command:

```
const role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

role.permissions.add('SEND_MESSAGES')
```

If you want to understand why this will work, here are some relevant docs links: [role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role), [permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions), and the [permissions flags](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

EDIT:
To change the permissions for the specific channels, just do:

```
const role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

message.channel.overwritePermissions(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': false })
```

and to give them back, you would do the following

```
const role = guild.roles.find("name", "Verified ");

message.channel.overwritePermissions(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': true})
```

Comment: I only want to lock the channel I sent >lock in

Comment: Oh, in that case you need to change `role.permissions.remove('SEND_MESSAGES')` to `message.channel.overwritePermissions(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': false })`, I'll update my previous answer for you now.

Comment: It says guild is not defined.

Comment: are you calling it in a DM

Comment: The problem was that I'm using discord.js v12 so I had to do message.guild.roles.cache.find

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this

```
const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member') 
message.channel.updateOverwrite(role2,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': false}) 
message.channel.send("Successfully locked **${message.channel.name}**")
```

and this for unlock

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member') 
message.channel.updateOverwrite(role,{ 'SEND_MESSAGES': true})   
message.channel.send("Successfully unlocked **${message.channel.name}**")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this question was already answered, thanks.

Comment: yes but that command didn't worked for me.

Comment: try the one that was marked as the answer, also if you don't understand how to read this code, it locks the channel for the Member role only, not everyone.